# Why does my nltk 'for' loop repeat results instead of moving to the next sentence?

Tags: python, function, nlp, nltk, nested-for-loop

Let's imagine I have these 5 sentences in the df2['CleanDescr'] after removing stop words and lemmatization:

```
garcia cash drawer reconciliation report distribution hill specialty
jiang report not delivered oic surgical minute
rosario requesting case log - chadwycke r. smith
villalta clarity report - "solid organ transplant"
wallace need assistance with monthly clarity report
```

I tried to run the nltk.tag.pos_tag for each sentence in 2 different ways, but they kept repeating after the first sentence. These are the 2 ways I did it:

include_tags = {'NN', 'VB', 'PRP', 'VBZ', 'VBP', 'VPB', 'VBD', 'NNS', 'NNPS'}

1.

```
def remove_tag(tagset):
    for word in df2['CleanDescr']:
        tagged_sent = nltk.tag.pos_tag(word.split())
        #print(tagged_sent)
        edited_sent = ' '.join([words for words,tag in tagged_sent if tag in include_tags])
        #print(edited_sent)
        return edited_sent

df2['CleanDescr'] = df2['CleanDescr'].apply(remove_tag)
df2['CleanDescr']
```

2. 

```
def remove_tag(tagset):
    for word in df2['CleanDescr']:
        tagged_sent = nltk.tag.pos_tag(word.split())
        #print(tagged_sent)
        for tag in tagged_sent:
            if tag in include_tags:
                edited_sent = ' '.join()
                return edited_sent

df2['CleanDescr'] = df2['CleanDescr'].apply(remove_tag)
df2['CleanDescr']
```

The result is supposed to run through all 5 sentences. Instead, they repeat after the first sentence. Here's my result:

```
0        garcia cash drawer distribution hill specialty...
1        garcia cash drawer distribution hill specialty...
2        garcia cash drawer distribution hill specialty...
3        garcia cash drawer distribution hill specialty...
4        garcia cash drawer distribution hill specialty...
```

Comment: The `return` statement ends the function, so the loop stops. So version 1 only processes the first row of `df2['CleanDescr']`. Version 2 stops when it sees the first tag in `include_tags`.

Comment: What is `edited_sent = ' '.join()` supposed to do? You're missing the argument to `join()`

Comment: `apply` runs function on every row in dataframe and it gives you this row in `tagset` and you should work with this `tagset` but you run `df2['CleanDescr']` inside this function so you work with all dataframe  in every execution - and this makes no sense.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you for your help! I think it works, but it's just taking so long to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apply()` runs function on every row separatelly and it gives you this row in `tagset` and you should work with this `tagset` but you run `for`-loop with `df2['CleanDescr']` inside this function so you work with all dataframe in
every execution - and this makes no sense.

Frankly, it should rather have name `sentence` or `sent` instead of `tagset`.

```
def remove_tag(sent):
    tagged_sent = nltk.tag.pos_tag(sent.split())
    edited_sent = ' '.join([words for words, tag in tagged_sent if tag in include_tags])
    return edited_sent
```

```
import pandas as pd
import nltk

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'CleanDescr': [    
        'garcia cash drawer reconciliation report distribution hill specialty',
        'jiang report not delivered oic surgical minute',
        'rosario requesting case log - chadwycke r. smith',
        'villalta clarity report - "solid organ transplant"',
        'wallace need assistance with monthly clarity report',
    ]
})
                  

include_tags = {'NN', 'VB', 'PRP', 'VBZ', 'VBP', 'VPB', 'VBD', 'NNS', 'NNPS'}

def remove_tag(sent):
    tagged_sent = nltk.tag.pos_tag(sent.split())
    edited_sent = ' '.join([words for words, tag in tagged_sent if tag in include_tags])
    return edited_sent

df['CleanDescr'] = df['CleanDescr'].apply(remove_tag)
print(df['CleanDescr'])
```

Result:

```
0    garcia cash drawer reconciliation report distr...
1                                  jiang report minute
2                      rosario case chadwycke r. smith
3                           clarity report transplant"
4                    wallace assistance clarity report
Name: CleanDescr, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Let me try that on my dataset.